# Можно ли в таблице бд использовать php

Tags: php

Можно ли в таблице бд использовать php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, в принципе, можно, если потом будете эту переменную запускать, а не просто выводить в печать. Подсказываю пример

```
 $d="
    mt_srand(time());\$max=10;
    \$a=array(6,3,2,2,2,5);
    print_r(\$a);";
    eval($d);
```

Переменная $d получает код из базы. Помните, что код должен быть чисто пхп. И второе!  Эскапирование должно уже быть. То есть - экранирование кавычек и знаков доллара.

Answer (score 1):

БД может содержать что угодно, можешь весь сайт в базу засунуть))

К слову, история из раздела фантастики:

Данные:         
Хостинг с 1мб памяти        
Сервер баз данных с 500мб памяти

Цель:    
Разместить сайт на хостинге

Решение:   
Заливаем весь сайт в бд, более менее структурно распределяем данные по базе.     
Пишем index.php с набором запросов к бд.

p.s.     
База данных должна хранить лишь данные которые так или иначе могут изменяться (настройки, информацию, пользователей и тд, как в джумле к примеру)
Так же в базе приемлимо хранить списки которые не изменяются но являются очень длинными 
Структура приложения не должна попадать в БД, структура отражена набором таблиц и их связями

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - закодировать нужный вам код функцией **base64_encode**, записать результат в базу, а выполнить вот так :

```
$execCode = 'код из базы данных';
eval ( base64_decode( $execCode ) );
```

Но так лучше не делать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, если в виде текста. php-функции БД не поймет и не выполнит.

Comment: Смотря какая БД. [PL/php][1]

  [1]: https://public.commandprompt.com/projects/plphp/wiki

Answer (score 0):

ТС - если вы реально планируете что-то таким образом реализовывать, а не просто из интереса, то вы явно двигаетесь в неправильном направлении. Так сделать, конечно, можно, но делать так не надо.